# Invalid bundle when starting Apache Karaf

Tags: spring, apache-camel, apache-karaf

I have a curious behavior when I start my Karaf.

My JAR bundle contains a simple camel spring xml route that transforms an incoming xml fragment to text with an xslt. I use a BridgePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer to externalize my properties into {karaf.base}/etc/karaf-invalid-bundle.cfg.

To illustrate my post, I created a github repository https://github.com/johanlelan/Karaf-invalid-bundle-example.

Occasionally, my bundle fails to start for a strange cause:

```
karaf@root> log:display-exception
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException:     Failed to create route error.sample at: >>> To[xslt:xslt/template.xslt] <
<< in route: Route(error.sample)[[From[ref:incoming.endpoint]] -> [SetHea... because of     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid BundleContext.
        at     org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapRuntimeCamelException(ObjectHelper.java:1352)[113:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.2]
        at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.onApplicationEvent(SpringCamelContext.java:120)[121:org.apache.camel.camel-spring:2.12.2]
        at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean.onApplicationEvent(CamelContextFactoryBean.java:301)[121:org.apache.camel.camel-spring:2.12.2]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:96)[78:org.springframework.context:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:334)[78:org.springframework.context:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:948)[78:org.springframework.context:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractOsgiBundleApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractOsgiBundleApplicationContext.java:235)[117:org.springframework.osgi.core:1.2.1]
        at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext$4.run(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:358)[117:org.springframework.osgi.core:1.2.1]
        at org.springframework.osgi.util.internal.PrivilegedUtils.executeWithCustomTCCL(PrivilegedUtils.java:85)[117:org.springframework.osgi.core:1.2.1]
        at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.completeRefresh(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:320)[117:org.springframework.osgi.core:1.2.1]
        at org.springframework.osgi.extender.internal.dependencies.startup.DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor$CompleteRefreshTask.run(DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.java:132)[118:org.springframework.osgi.extender:1.2.1]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)[:1.6.0_45]
Caused by: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route error.sample at: >>> To[xslt:xslt/template.xslt] <<< in route: Route(error.sample)[[From[ref:incoming.endpoint]] -> [SetHea... because of java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid BundleContext.
        at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:912)[113:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.2]
        at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:177)[113:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.2]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRoute(DefaultCamelContext.java:770)[113:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.2]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:1914)[113:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.2]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:1670)[113:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.2]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:1544)[113:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.2]
        at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.doStart(SpringCamelContext.java:179)[121:org.apache.camel.camel-spring:2.12.2]
        at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)[113:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.2]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:1512)[113:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.2]
        at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.maybeStart(SpringCamelContext.java:228)[121:org.apache.camel.camel-spring:2.12.2]
        at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.onApplicationEvent(SpringCamelContext.java:118)[121:org.apache.camel.camel-spring:2.12.2]
        ... 10 more
Caused by: org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid BundleContext.
        at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapRuntimeCamelException(ObjectHelper.java:1352)[113:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.2]
        at org.apache.camel.core.osgi.OsgiServiceRegistry.findByTypeWithName(OsgiServiceRegistry.java:110)[121:org.apache.camel.camel-spring:2.12.2]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.CompositeRegistry.findByTypeWithName(CompositeRegistry.java:87)[113:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.2]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.PropertyPlaceholderDelegateRegistry.findByTypeWithName(PropertyPlaceholderDelegateRegistry.java:70)[113:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.DefaultChannel.getOrCreateBacklogTracer(DefaultChannel.java:339)[113:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.DefaultChannel.initChannel(DefaultChannel.java:202)[113:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.2]
        at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.wrapChannel(ProcessorDefinition.java:269)[113:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.2]
        at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.wrapProcessor(ProcessorDefinition.java:251)[113:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.2]
        at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.makeProcessor(ProcessorDefinition.java:507)[113:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.2]
        at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.addRoutes(ProcessorDefinition.java:213)[113:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.2]
        at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:909)[113:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.2]
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid BundleContext.
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.checkValidity(BundleContextImpl.java:514)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.0.3.jar:]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.getAllServiceReferences(BundleContextImpl.java:411)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.0.3.jar:]
        at org.apache.camel.core.osgi.OsgiServiceRegistry.findByTypeWithName(OsgiServiceRegistry.java:94)[121:org.apache.camel.camel-spring:2.12.2]
    ... 29 more
karaf@root>
```

I think that this error is linked to my properties or to my BundleActivator class.
Any ideas on the way to stop this behavior?

Johan

Comment: Can you remove the properties setting up and try it again?

Comment: @WillemJiang : When I remove my properties setting, I can not reproduce this error. I do not know if it's linked but every startup works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about your concrete problem in spring. I stopped using spring on OSGi a long time ago.

A much easier solution would be to just use blueprint instead of spring. You can then use the config admin support of blueprint to attach to the config file in etc. BLueprint runs much smoother in OSGi than spring dm.

You also have the advantage that config admin properties configured by blueprint are automatically available as camel properties.

Comment: I am not familiar with blueprint. I have constraints like creating java classes from xsd and using custom java beans into my camel routes. I don't know if blueprint can do it?

Comment: You can use blueprint for the camel context and mix it with a routebuilder in java dsl. So you should have all camel features.

Comment: It works perfectly on blueprint. thanks C. Schneider. I read your blog and I try to create an example of camel cxfrs blueprint (https://github.com/johanlelan/camel-cxfrs-blueprint-example). It runs and works great but I am not satisfied of my unit tests. In fact, I have an exception on. Christian, have you a unit test strategy for cxf endpoint?